# Show more search results in Solr

Tags: solr

I want to search with given keyword  differently. For example:
If any one searches for "solr search" it must return result both for 'solr' and followed by 'search' result. How to do it?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you would parse the search string yourself into tokens, and do a search for each token.

Comment: Do you mean a phrase query like "solr search" rather a `solr OR search`? Or `solr AND search`?

Comment: Yes I want to do Tokenizing search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think the easiest way is to do it with boolean terms. Just search for "solr OR search" and the results you wanted will be shown. But one thing: Solr will also show you results with both searchterms in it. Don´t know if you want this too.

You can also use the OR operator as your default one. Just open your schema.xml and modify this line:

```
<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND"/>
```

to

```
<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>
```